# Download mp3 for offline use in android studio

Tags: android, download, podcast

I am making a podcast app in android studio and i want to be able to download the different episodes so the user can listen to them when being offline. Pretty much like spotify. But i don't want to download them to the public user storage, instead i want to download them in an internal app storage, if such thing exists. The DownloadManager documentation from android wasn't any help. Hope you can help me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Android data-storage developer docs here [Android data-storage developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific)  and specifically check out the **Internal storage directories** and **Access persistent files** parts.

You can use `context.getFilesDir()` to "get a file representing an internal directory for your app" so you should be able to use this to create a private storage location to save your podcast files to which other apps cannot access.

Comment: Ill give it a try and let you know how it works. But thank you very much this looks promising :)

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot! Here is some code for future visitors that worked instantly. Only minor adjustments were made: https://gist.github.com/vadimTovstik/1591c6a7c6a70c6edc0a642c29ea505a